# Android Build Failure: Could not find flexbox-2.0.1.aar

Tags: android, gradle, build, flexbox, jcenter

When I try to build/run the app I get the following error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Failed to transform flexbox-2.0.1.aar (com.google.android:flexbox:2.0.1) to match attributes {artifactType=android-aar-metadata, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Could not find flexbox-2.0.1.aar (com.google.android:flexbox:2.0.1).
        Searched in the following locations:
            https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/flexbox/2.0.1/flexbox-2.0.1.aar

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 13s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Any idea on how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the issue is that the dependency `flexbox-2.0.1` was hosted on `jcenter()`, which has been shut down.

One solution to solve this issue is to remove the `jcenter()` repository from all of the repositories objects in the `build.gradle` **(Project Level)** file and add a mirror repository for it, such as **Aliyun Mirror**, for example:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.8.22'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
-       jcenter()
+       maven { url "https://maven.aliyun.com/repository/jcenter" }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
-       jcenter()
+       maven { url "https://maven.aliyun.com/repository/jcenter" }
    }
}
```